# How to read micr line in C#

Tags: c#, windows

can any one help me out i m new to c#

i have scanned a check and from that i want to read micr line and get the details of bank routing number and check number from the MICR line in c# and i m working this in windows application

```
 public static string ReadOneMICR(string file, int page)
            {
                try
                {
                    string sout = "";
                    mut.WaitOne();      // Prevent reentrancy 
                    ClearMicr.CcMicrReader reader = new ClearMicr.CcMicrReader();
                    reader.Image.Open(file, page);
                    // Do actual reading  
                    reader.FindMICR();
                    // Display results 
                    if (reader.MicrCount > 0)
                    {
                        ClearMicr.CcMicr Micr = reader.get_MicrLine(1);
                        sout = sout + "MICR Type: " + Micr.DocumentType + Environment.NewLine;
                        if (Micr.Routing.IsRead)
                            sout = sout + "Routing = " + Micr.Routing.TextANSI + Environment.NewLine;
                        if (Micr.AuxOnUs.IsRead)
                            sout = sout + "AuxOnUs = " + Micr.AuxOnUs.TextANSI + Environment.NewLine;
                        if (Micr.OnUs.IsRead)
                            sout = sout + "OnUs = " + Micr.OnUs.TextANSI + Environment.NewLine;
                        if (Micr.Amount.IsRead)
                            sout = sout + "Amount = " + Micr.Amount.TextANSI + Environment.NewLine;
                        if (Micr.Account.IsRead)
                            sout = sout + "Account = " + Micr.Account.TextANSI + Environment.NewLine;
                        if (Micr.CheckNumber.IsRead)
                            sout = sout + "CheckNumber = " + Micr.CheckNumber.TextANSI + Environment.NewLine;
                    }
                    else
                        sout = "No MICR found";
                    return sout;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return ("ERROR: " + ex.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    mut.ReleaseMutex();
                    System.GC.Collect();
                }
            }
```

here is sample code and i m facing issues in the above code for get_MicrLine and TextANSI lines please clarify me and provide me a bug free code for reading micr line in check

Comment: Is there a problem with the code?  Have you narrowed it down at all?

Comment: as Drew hints, it's difficult to help you if you don't tell us exactly *what* the problem is. Please take the time to read this interesting article about asking good questions: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 2):

You haven't said what your error is, but you might try this replacement line:

```
ClearMicr.CcMicr Micr = reader.MicrLine[1];
```

Comment: Haha, +1 for psychic debugging :)

Comment: I have included ClearMicr reference and called the same as library but still do not contain the definition get_MicrLine and missing the assembly reference or directive... this is the bug i m facing